# Report Builder 3.0 Charts - Need to show empty category groups

Tags: sql-server, bar-chart, reportbuilder

I am using SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 to create a bar chart.  The chart is a count of satisfaction scores (Excellent, Very Good, Good, Fair, Poor), with a bar showing each of the respective scores.  It works beautifully, except in the case where there are no records with a specific score.  I would like to be able to show all of the options, even if there is a value of zero.  Is there a way to put a placeholder there or otherwise force it to show?

Answer (score 0):

Create another table that contains all of the category names.

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES(ID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then insert the category names into the table.

```
INSERT INTO CATEGORIES
VALUES ('Excellent', 'Very Good', 'Good', 'Fair', 'Poor');
```

Then for your bar chart dataset,

```
SELECT C.ID, COUNT(A.ID)
FROM Categories C
LEFT OUTER JOIN yourTableNameHere A on C.ID = A.category
GROUP BY C.ID;
```

The result will be a dataset with (CategoryName, Count) records.